# Rollback not working coldfusion transaction

Tags: coldfusion, transactions

I'm using cfscript with a transaction, but it keep the record in the database even though I call the rollback. I'm calling the rollback inside the try not the catch because I need to validate it there.

Here is my code:

```
transaction action="begin"{
try{
    rollbackAction = false;
    // Insert into CustomerBilling
    insertCustomerBilling = new query();
    insertCustomerBilling.setDatasource("rent");
    insertCustomerBilling.setName("insertCustomerBilling");
    insertCustomerBilling.addParam(name="CustomerID",   value="#CompanyID#",    cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
    insertCustomerBilling.addParam(name="Cost", value="#Cost#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal");
    insertCustomerBilling.addParam(name="BillDate", value="#DateFormat(Now(), 'yyyy/mm/dd')#",  cfsqltype="cf_sql_datetime");
    insertCustomerBilling.addParam(name="PaidDate", value="#DateFormat(Now(), 'yyyy/mm/dd')#",  cfsqltype="cf_sql_datetime");
    result = insertCustomerBilling.execute(sql="INSERT INTO CustomerBilling " &
                        " (CustomerID, Cost, BillDate, Paid, PaidDate, PropertyID, BillTypeID) " &
                        " VALUES(:CustomerID, :Cost, :BillDate, 0, :PaidDate, 0, 1 )");

    GetCCExemption = new query();
    GetCCExemption.setDatasource("rent");
    GetCCExemption.setName("GetCCExemption");
    GetCCExemption.addParam(name="CompanyID",   value="#CompanyID#",    cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
    result = GetCCExemption.execute(sql="Select * From Billing_CCExemptions Where CompanyID = :CompanyID");
    rs = result.getResult();
    if(rs.recordCount <= 0){
        // Check if we inserted customer into Stripe_Customer
        GetStripeCustomer = new query();
        GetStripeCustomer.setDatasource("rent");
        GetStripeCustomer.setName("GetStripeCustomer");
        GetStripeCustomer.addParam(name="CompanyID",    value="#CompanyID#",    cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
        resultSC = GetStripeCustomer.execute(sql="Select * From Stripe_Customer Where CompanyID = :CompanyID");
        rsSC = resultSC.getResult();
        if(rsSC.recordCount > 0){
            // Charge
            charge = oStripe.chargeCustomer();
        } else{
            // Notify us we haven't inserted into Stripe_Customer
            mailerService = new mail();
            mailerService.setTo('test@test.com');
            mailerService.setFrom("support@test.com");
            mailerService.setSubject("Error");
            mailerService.setType("html");
            mailBody = "ERROR";
            mailerService.send(body=mailBody);
            transaction action="rollback"; 

            rollbackAction = true;
        }
    }
    if(!rollbackAction){
        transaction action="commit"; 
    }
} catch(any e){
    transaction action="rollback";  
}
```

}

Does anyone know why the rollback isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: try/catch is for whether or not the code actually executes, not for whether it provides the desired results.

Comment: ok. What do you mean?

Comment: This, `I'm calling the rollback inside the try not the catch`, contradicts this `catch(any e){
    transaction action="rollback";  `.

Comment: I see... a rollback can only be called inside a catch?

Comment: I agree with Dan's suggestion... A bit off topic, but some quick code review: I'd recommend not creating cfparameters for BillDate and PaidDate. Just use the database's SysDateTime() or GetDate() functionality for a Now() equivalent. At the very least, don't bother DateFormat() on it, especially if the database datatype is date/datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
    if(!rollbackAction){
        transaction action="commit"; 
    }
} catch(any e){
    transaction action="rollback";
```

to this

```
if(!rollbackAction){
    transaction action="commit"; 
}
else
    transaction action="rollback";
```

Your catch block only executes if the try block experiences a runtime error.  Runtime errors mean, "did not execute".  They have nothing to do with unwanted results.